# Windows 8 User Settings Disappeared

Tags: windows-8, user-accounts

I recently reformatted my machine and have been using Windows 8 Pro successfully for quite some time now. However, I just noticed that whenever I tried copying and pasting data in the Program Files, it acted like it succeeded. However, none of the changes were made. I thought, well, it is most likely something to do with my User Account being a Microsoft Login so I tried to change this to a local account in the PC Settings. However, the Users option doesn't appear. I even enabled the Administrator account and logged in as the local admin (This is a home computer, not part of any domain) and it also did not have the Users option. Any idea what is going on before I go through another reformat? I have not  installed anything crazy on this machine, just VirtualBox, Chrome, Sublime Text, Blender and Avast Antivirus.

[image]

Comment: The option to disconnect the Microsoft Account should be in the "Sync your Settings" panel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be a bug within Windows 8. A reinstallation of Windows 8 did not have the same issue. A repair did not fix the issue.